# Apply styling when user holds mouse click down?

Tags: css

I have a button in my project that I am trying to remove the `outline` attribute, which is defaulted on for the CSS theme being used. I'm able to apply the CSS rule for the button when no pseudo-class is applied, and for `:hover` and `:focus`.

However, when I click down and hold with my mouse or trackpad, I still see the outline, even with an `:active` rule applied.

Here's my CSS (overriding the default theme, this is not CSS from the theme itself):

```
// even with this :focus and :active rule, I get the outline
// when holding down mouse / trackpad selection
.AddButton, .AddButton:focus, .AddButton:active {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  border: solid 2px #4a4a4a;
  outline: 0; // the relevant attribute
}

.AddButton:hover {
  background-color: #3baeff;
  border: solid 2px #3baeff;
  color: #ffffff;
}
```

What CSS selector do I need to use to override the default behavior? Thanks!

Comment: Use JavaScript?

Comment: I think you should you javascript to get the event: "onmousedown" for this case because I think Css do not support this unless you use external library.

Comment: can we have a live example here?

Comment: You probably don't really want to remove that outline.  It's there for a reason.  https://a11yproject.com/posts/never-remove-css-outlines/ http://www.outlinenone.com/

Comment: @jmargolisvt That's not helpful, it's an opinion not a technical answer. This is a valid question for understanding CSS behavior. That opinion about outlines is perhaps fine, but some clients want different behavior.

Comment: @Mr.Brickowski I will provide a live example, should have done that first. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution turned out to be hard to find, but straightforward:

```
.AddButton:hover:active {
  outline: 0;
}
```

Comment: `:active` was enough for buttons but not for `a` tags.
it does work for `a` tags too.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to manually handle each elements' state and its corresponding styling. If you apply a style to an element without pseudo-class, it would also cover its different state like `:hover`, `:active` etc. Remember [css specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity)? Consider below, the button caption is always red, no matter hover or focus, unless we specify a more specific rule `:active`, then the caption turns blue when it is pressed. We 
don't need attach listener to its `mousein`, `mouseout`, `mouseover` event to handle its focus or hover state styling.

```css
button {
  color: red;
}

button:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>OK</button>
```

One possible reason to your problem is you mentioned there is a style defined

> defaulted on for the CSS theme being used.

Maybe inside there has a more specific rule to define the `:focus` and `:active` style, then you need to override them. Still you don't need event to handle style, just css itself is enough.

Demonstrate below. If a hover style is defined for green, you can still override that by a more specific rule, e.g. id selector, to make it stay red on hover.

```css
/***********site default css***********/

button:hover {
  color: green;
}

/***************override***************/

button,
#stay-red {
  color: red;
}

button:active {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<button>green on hover</button>
<button id="stay-red">stay red</button>
```

Comment: I understand CSS, for the most part, I'm trying to sort out this corner case. So the second half of your question is more helpful. However, as you can see from my CSS snippet, I am setting CSS (and overriding the theme) for the button, and the relevant pseudo-classes. However, it's not sufficient. The outline still shows when I'm holding the click down over the button (holding mouse down / trackpad down).

Comment: Then you have to check how the theme's outline rule is written. I think the it has greater specificity so your rule cannot override that. Find that out, and make some changes to your rules so you can have more specificity over the theme's. Then you can eliminate the outline.

Answer (score 0):

The css active selector is triggered when an element is held down or clicked upon. The hover selector is triggered when the cursor hovers over the element.

```css
#btn:hover { outline:1px solid red; }
#btn:active { outline:none; }
```

```html
<button id="btn">red outline on hover, no outline on click</button>
```